# React Router 4, how to check for a possible redirect on all routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In my app, after a user signs up, I need the user to confirm their email address before being able to use the app.

If the user is authenticated `state.currentUser.isLoggedIn`, I want to run a check like so:

```
if (!state.currentUser.confirmed) {
   redirect to "/welcome/verify-your-email)
}
```

Unless, the user is within the "/welcome" path, as I want the user to be able to sign up, create their profile and then verify their email before being able to access the app.

With React Router 4, how can I make this happen in my Routes file?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and didn't find a better solution than checking history props action property:

```
const { history } = this.props;
const isRedirect = history.action === 'REPLACE';
```

Note that you have to use `withRouter` utility of `react-router-dom` to reliably access history from props.